# Creating a Calculation in an Analysis cube to produce a Distinct Count by criteria

Tags: ssas

I have a multi-dimensional cube that has multiple rows for each shop. There is a ShopCount measure that is a DistinctCount over the ShopKey field in the cube, which is in another measure group. I can get Shop counts over all sorts of different dimensions, which in this case is usually location. That works fine.

Now I want a variant of this. I want an inline distinct count of shops based on another measure or dimension.

Here is an example mdx that gives me a distinct count of shops for a particular month, where the shop type is either automotive or camping.

```
SELECT [Measures].[Shop Count] ON COLUMNS
FROM [Retail Cube]
WHERE ([Report Date].[Month].[201905],
       {[Shop].[ShopType].&[Automotive],[Shop].[ShopType].&[Camping]})
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

In Excel, I would like to be able to get another column that has the distinct count of Automotive and Camping shops over the range of months in my database. I would like to then be able to filter the columns by all the existing dimensions that I am currently filtering by.

I tried creating a calculated field in the Calculations tab, such as:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [Shop].[ShopType].&[Automotive] THEN [Shop].[Shop Key] 
                    WHEN [Shop].[ShopType].&[Camping] THEN [Shop].[Shop Key] 
                    ELSE NULL END)
```

(Note: Shop Key is what I do my Distinct Count over)

After substantial processing it came up with an error in that column.

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?